# Finding marginals of the uniform distribution on a triangle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The statement is:
Random vector $(X, Y)$ is uniformly distributed on a triangle $A = (0, 0)$, $B = (2, 0)$, $C = (1, 1)$. Find distribution and density functions of $X, Y$. Check if $X, Y$ are independent

This is my try:

Triangle can be described through the following equations: $y = 0$, $y = x$, $y = -x + 2$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& p(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{S}, & (x, y) \in A B C \\
0, & (x, y) \notin A B C
\end{array}= \begin{cases}1, & (x, y) \in A B C \\
0, & (x, y) \notin A B C\end{cases} \right. \\
\\ 
& p_{1}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x, y) d y=2 \int_0^x d y=\left.2 \cdot y\right|_0 ^x=2 x, x \in[0,2]
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
p_2(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x, y) d x=2 \int_y^1 d x=2(1-y)=2-2 y, y \in[0,1]
$$
Then I try to check them for independence:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \mathbb{E}_x=\int_{-\infty}^4 p_1(x) x d x=\int_0^2 2 x^2 d x=\frac{16}{3} \\
& \mathbb{E}_y=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_2(y) y d y=\int_0^0 2 y-2 y^2 d y=\frac{1}{3} \\
& \operatorname{cov}(x, y)=\iint\left(x-\mathbb{E}_x\right)\left(y-\mathbb{E}_y\right) p(x, y) d x d y= \\
& =\iint\left(x-\frac{6}{3}\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{3}\right) d x d y=\int_0^2\left(x-\frac{16}{3}\right) d x \int_0^x\left(y-\frac{1}{3}\right) d y= \\
& =\left.\int_0^2\left(x-\frac{16}{3}\right) d x\left(\frac{1}{2} y^2-\frac{1}{3} y\right)\right|_0 ^x=-\frac{22}{9} \Rightarrow \text {they are dependent } \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

So my questions are:

1. Did I find density functions and covariance correct? I used triangles symmetry but I’m not sure that is a correct way to do that?
2. What is a correct way to find distribution functions?

Edit: I see now that integral of x density function is not 1, but I can’t figure out what’s wrong

Edit2: Fixed p2(x), but still not sure about distribution functions

Comment: For the marginal of $X$, you're integrating $dy$ from $0$ to $x$, which are only the correct endpoints on the left side of the triangle $0<x<1$. On the right side $1<x<2$, the top should be $2-x$. For independence, you don't have to calculate the covariance. You can just calculate the conditional distribution of $x$ and show that it depends on $y$.

Comment: @jwhite oh, i see, got it, thanks! i havent learned conditional distribution yet but i will look it up

Comment: Just look at $\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant 1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant 1|Y\leqslant 1/2)$. If these are not equal, then $X$ and $Y$ can't be independent.

Comment: @jwhite oh, ok, thanks!
about marginal X: do i understand correctly that it just gonna be x for 0<x<1 and 2 - x for 1<x<2?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.